# How to Pass dynamic array to ajax post Body?(Beginner)

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am having problem passing array to a ajax post body.Please provide answer purely on Javascript and Ajax

```
function js_addToCheckOut (theForm) {    

   for (var i=0; i < theForm.circSelected.length; i++)
                 {
                       if(theForm.circSelected[i].checked) {        
                        myarray[i] = theForm.circSelected[i].value;
                        vCheckedCount =vCheckedCount +1;

                    }
                }

                   var url = "search_pkg.save_item_ids?vitemids";
                   var urlParams = "";
                   var urlParams1 = "";
                   var xmlhttp = js_getXMLHTTPRequest();
                   var xmlContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
                   urlParams1 =myarray; ---how to pass array here as parameter
                   urlParams = urlParams1;
                   xmlhttp.open("POST", url, true);
                   xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", xmlContentType);
                   xmlhttp.send(urlParams);
                   theForm.action = ("search_pkg.add_to_check_out?vitemids="+xmlhttp.responseText);
             }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll suggest you to use jQuery
https://jquery.com/

Using jquery:

```
$.post(url, {dynamic_array: []}, function(response){
  // Do something with your response
});
```

If you wants to use only native XHR: Read the docs about class FormData - https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/FormData

It's should help you to build request body.

```
var array = [...];
var body = new FormData();
for ( var i = 0; i < array.length; i++ ) {
    body.append('field[]', array[i]);
}

xhr.send(body);
```

Comment: Can you please tell me how to get this done in javascript and ajax

Comment: Or you can use pretty lightweight my library: https://github.com/Max201/miraxjs - mx.http({url: "/login", method: "post"}, function(response){ });

Comment: can you tell me how to pass array in xmlhttp.send()?